# Sizes attribute for Bootstrap responsive breakpoints

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, bootstrap-4, srcset

I'm working on optimization on my page and it was all going smoothly since I came up with an idea to implement `srcset` and `sizes` attributes to my `<img>`. I create `php` function that constructs `img` object and fills `srcset` attribute with new scaled images (extra-1200w,large-992w,medium-786w,small-576w,extra_small-320w) and universal (as much as it can be done) `sizes` attribute (example below).
The problem starts occurs when I start using miscellaneous [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for different `vw`(view width), for example `col-lg-4 col-md-6`.
I tried many different versions of `sizes` but it didn't seem to work except one:

`sizes="(min-width: 36em) calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)), 100vw"`

this works, but for one grid - in this example `.333` which is `col-4`. (`12em` is sidenav width).

But for more than one grid I tried this:

```
sizes="(max-width: 575.98px) 100vw,
        ((min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px)) 100vw,
        ((min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px)) calc(.5 * 100vw),
        ((min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)) calc(.333 * 100vw),
        ((min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1440.98px)) calc(.333 * 100vw),
        (min-width: 1441px) calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)),
        100vw"
```

and for some reason, it always displays image with "extra" size.

An example below. it's the middle one. Every image is signed by its own size.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="fixed-sn mdb-skin-custom customize-support" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#scrollspy" data-offset="15" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Section: Page content -->
            <section>
                <!--Section: Basic resources-->
                <section class="text-center">
                    <!--Grid row-->
<div class="row">

                        <!--Grid column-->
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">

                            <!--Card-->
                            <div class="card">
            
                            <!--Card image-->
                            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bf-tutorial.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a id="home-resources-automation-img" href="#">
                                    <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
            
                            <!--Card content-->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!--Title-->
                                <h4 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h4>
                                <!--Text-->
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet.
                                </p>
                                <a id="home-resources-automation-button" href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-dtc btn-md waves-effect waves-light">Learn more</a>
                            </div>
                            <!--/.Card content-->
            
                        </div>
                            <!--/.Card-->

                        </div>
                        <!--Grid column-->

                        <!--Grid column-->
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">

                            <!--Card-->
                            <div class="card">

                                <!--Card image-->
                                <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                                    <!-- <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="MDB Bootstrap tutorial"> -->
                                    <img src="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap.jpg" srcset="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-extra.jpg 1200w, https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-large.jpg 992w, https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-medium.jpg 768w, https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-small.jpg 576w, https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-extra-small.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 575.98px) 100vw,
                               ((min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px)) 100vw,
                               ((min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px)) calc(.5 * 100vw),
                               ((min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)) calc(.333 * 100vw),
                               ((min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1440.98px)) calc(.333 * 100vw),
                               ((min-width: 1441px) and (min-width: 36em)) calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)),
                               100vw" alt="MDB Bootstrap tutorial" class="img-fluid">                                    <a id="home-resources-tutorial-img" href="#">
                                        <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <!--/.Card image-->

                                <!--Card content-->
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <!--Title-->
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h4>
                                    <!--Text-->
                                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                    </p>
                                    <a id="home-resources-tutorial-button" href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-dtc btn-md waves-effect waves-light">Start</a>
                                </div>
                                <!--/.Card content-->

                            </div>
                            <!--/.Card-->

                        </div>
                        <!--Grid column-->

                        <!--Grid column-->
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">


                        <!--Card-->
                        <div class="card">
            
                            <!--Card image-->
                            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bf-tutorial.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a id="home-resources-automation-img" href="#">
                                    <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
            
                            <!--Card content-->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!--Title-->
                                <h4 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h4>
                                <!--Text-->
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet.
                                </p>
                                <a id="home-resources-automation-button" href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-dtc btn-md waves-effect waves-light">Learn more</a>
                            </div>
                            <!--/.Card content-->
            
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Card-->

                        </div>
                        <!--Grid column-->

                    </div>
                    <!--Grid row-->
                </section>
            </section>
            <!-- Section: Page content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!--Main layout-->
</body>
```

my goal is to increase size proportionally to image width.

Any idea why this won't work?
Thanks in advance.

[example that works for one breakpoint](https://codepen.io/tombennet/pen/yYgLaQ)

EDIT.

pay attention to the fact that the smaller side does not mean that the photo should be smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33525915/171456) using (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594751/171456)) img "sizes" leaves it up to the browser to decide which image to use. It's simply a way to "suggest" images, but the browser may or may not because of caching and other factors.

To *consistently* **load images based on Bootstrap 4 breakpoints** you'll want to use a `<picture>`...

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-extra.jpg" media="(min-width: 1200px)" />
    <source srcset="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-large.jpg" media="(min-width: 992px)" />
    <source srcset="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-medium.jpg " media="(min-width: 768px)" />
    <source srcset="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-small.jpg" media="(min-width: 576px)" />
    <img src="https://acc02.mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Horizontal/6-col/bootstrap-extra-small.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
</picture>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/WbIpdEEFO6

Comment: picture tag is not using for optimization, but for `art direction` for example https://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/examples/3-08/pictureArtDirection/. and still, it takes page width, not `img` width which caused that image on 768px is smaller than at 767px, but the loaded image is bigger, which is not a big issue because with your answer and couple minutes of thinking I can get the result visually similar to what I want but not optimized unfortunately. Upvote for you anyway :) i will accept your answer is you make my sizes work :)

Comment: You mention browser caching and I must be missed that part of your answer. Browser always gives me biggest image from cached memory, that's why I always get the extra size and my query was good all this time. Thanks!!